# How to keep adding text to a cell line by line based on information in other cells

Tags: excel

Is there a keep adding text to a cell based on other cells? For example if columns A(Called Criteria 1) and B(called Criteria 2) and can have a number 0 or 1. I also have a third column C(called comments).

Is it possible to make column C type have texts printed out based on Columns A and B. For example if Column A(Criteria 1) is 0 and Column B(Criteria 2) is 1 then in column C, the following text will be in the cell, "Criteria 1 Failed.  Criteria 2 Passed".

Can someone show me an example of how this can be done.

Comment: Give this a try: `=A$1&" "&If(A2=0,"Failed,"Passed")&", "&B$1&" "&If(B2=0,"Failed,"Passed")`

Comment: `="Criteria 1 " & IF(A1=0,"Failed.","Passed.") & " " & "Criteria 2 " & IF(B1=0,"Failed.","Passed.")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Is there a way to make it go on different lines though.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It would help if you would mock up some data and expected outcome and paste it into the original post using edit.